# Jersey SubResource is slow

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I've not been able to understand why this sub-resource is taking so much.

The problem is that it takes around **2 minutes** to pass from `EventResource#getAttendeeSession()` to `AttendeeSessionResource#getAttendeeSessions()`

Taking a look in debug mode, the time is spent in `Stages.class` specifically in the line that says `lastStage.apply(continuation.result());` which is pure Jersey code so, my question is, what is wrong in this scenario ?

Is it because of it being a sub-resource of a sub-resource ? (don't thinks so)

With or without `locator.inject(resource);` the time is the same, 110 seconds avg.

### Root Resource

```
@Path("client") 
public class WebinarResource extends AbstractResource {
    @Path("{clientId}/event/{eventId}")
    public EventResource getEvent(@ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @PathParam("clientId") long clientId,
            @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @PathParam("eventId") long eventId) throws SQLException {
        EventResource resource = new EventResource(clientId, eventId);
        locator.inject(resource);

        return resource;
    }
}
```

### Sub Resource

```
public class EventResource extends AbstractResource{

    @Path("/attendeesession")
    public AttendeeSessionResource getAttendeeSession(){
        System.out.println("EventResoure#getAttendeeSession() called: " + LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println("curr time milis: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        AttendeeSessionResource resource = new AttendeeSessionResource();
        locator.inject(resource);

        return resource;
    }
}
```

### Sub - Sub Resource

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class AttendeeSessionResource extends AbstractResource{

    @PathParam("eventId") 
    private long eventId;
    //...

    @GET
    @WebinarSecurityFilter
    @WebinarThrottlingFilter(apiPrefix = "GET_EVENT_ATTENDEE_VIEWING_SESSIONS_", maxCallsPerMinute = MAX_CALLS_PER_MINUTE, endpointName = "Event-level Attendee Viewing Sessions")
    @WebinarClientValidationFilter
    @WebinarEventValidationFilter   
    public Response getAttendeeSessions(@QueryParam("sessiontype") String sessionType, @QueryParam("pageoffset") Integer pageOffset){
    System.out.println("AttendeeSessionResource#getAttendeeSessions() called: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    System.out.println("curr time milis: "+System.currentTimeMillis());     

    // THIS is the start of the resource method and it's already
    // been 110 seconds ??? why ?
    }
}
```